# Windbg .printf string alias from as /c

Tags: printf, alias, windbg, aliases

Hopefully this is a simple question, but if I define an alias `a1` as an expression `1+1` with `as /x a1 1+1` then I can display that via `.echo a1` **or** `.printf "a1 = %d", a1`.

Is it possible to do the same with `.printf` if I define an alias `a2` as a `CommandString` with `as /c a2 dv /t this`?

I can certainly `.echo` it, but trying something like `.printf "a2 = %ma", a2` gives a `Couldn't resolve error at` error, like:

```
.printf "a2 = %ma", a2
class Blah:Blah:Blah * this = 0x00000000194dacf0
 = Couldn't resolve error at 'class Blah::Blah::Blah * this = 0x00000000194dacf0
'
```

This is the same if `a2` is defined with `as /c a2 .printf "hello"`. I couldn't find examples of `.printf` being used to display string aliases otherwise I could just crib that... I thought it strange, unless I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
0:000> dv /t this
class Student * this = 0x000000c5`d6f6f910
0:000> as /c foo dv /t this
0:000> al
  Alias            Value  
 -------          ------- 
 foo              class Student * this = 0x000000c5`d6f6f910

0:000> .printf "${foo}"
class Student * this = 0x000000c5`d6f6f910
```

you accepted this but I was going to ask you this question in comment instead edited the answer

I answered the query but why are you trying to use %ma ?? it is supposed to print an ascii string in target virtual address space  like

```
0:000> .printf "%ma\n" , poi(poi(this)+8)
dave
```

edit usage of alias interpreter

```
0:000> .printf "to check if an alias is defined use ${/v:foo} ${/n:foo} == 1 \n" 
to check if an alias is defined use ${/v:foo} foo == 1 

0:000> .printf "to expand an alias  ${/n:foo} use ${/v:foo} == ${foo} " 
to expand an alias  foo use ${/v:foo} == class Student * this = 0x000000c5`d6f6f910
```

Comment: It wasn't `%ma` I was tied to, that was just something I'd tried as I couldn't figure out how to use `.printf` with an alias with a string value in it, and it worked for an expression / numeric value with `%d`. Really it was a question more about syntax... I knew _what_ I wanted to do, and that it _should_ be possible, but could find nothing indicating _how_ to do it.

Comment: ok just dump all these obtuse scripts alias etc  (yeah I can type them like a perlmonk but  I still suggest drop them) and embrace javascript  you can simply write legible scripts instead of @$foo-@$blah==@$confuing

Comment: well it is documented under ${alias interpreter} anyway I added an usage example

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be a bit confused about the way aliases work (and believe me it's perfectly normal, they're rather unintuitive! Took me some time to get how they work, and still I'm not 100% sure, but let me take a stab at your question!)

First, do not take aliases as "variables"! They're not symbolic names to keep certain values. They're more like, macros (that are replaced by a preprocessor if they're assigned).

To actually notice the difference, pay closer attention to the way `.printf "a1 = %d", a1` works. I don't know if we have different versions, or if it has to do with weird alias interpretation rule about "entering a new block", but, this is what I'm seeing:

```
0:000> as /x a1 1+1
0:000> .echo a1
0x2
0:000> .printf "a1 = %d", a1
0x2 = 2
```

Note that it's not saying `a1 = 2` but replacing `a1` inside the quote as well (or more like, wherever it sees it). It's as if **it's doing a string find and replace before executing the command!**

So, in your second example, again, it's string-replacing the output of that command both within the printf's format specifier quotes, and after (when it's used as an argument). And if that command output is not like a printf argument list, it's gonna get confused!

Rule of thumb with aliases is the bold sentence above I think. Take them as macros to be repleced by a preprocessor.

Comment: I may well be confused. ;-) However, this is helpful, as is the response below which gives me the syntax I wanted to see... little did I realise it would be just `.printf "${AliasName}"`.